# Como deixar esse código mais legível para alguém que não entende nada de programação?

Tags: python

Vou apresentar esse código para o meu professor de matemática (que sabe apenas de algoritmos, nada de Python ou qualquer linguagem de programação). Sou iniciante em Python, então sei que deve ter uma maneira mais simples de fazer o código.
O script é um jogo entre dois jogadores. Ele gera números aleatórios para serem multiplicados. Aquele que acertar o maior número entre os dois vence. Se os dois tiverem o mesmo número de acertos, a vitória vai para aquele que necessitou de menos tempo para responder.

```
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint
# Listas do jogador 1
gabarito_j1 = list()  # Lista com respostas da multiplicação
respostas_j1 = list()  # Lista com os inputs do usuário
resultado_j1 = list()  # Lista comparando gabarito e repostas
tempo_j1 = list()  # Lista com o tempo levado pelo usuário
# Listas do jogador 2
gabarito_j2 = list()
respostas_j2 = list()
resultado_j2 = list()
tempo_j2 = list()

rodadas = int(input('Insira o número de rodadas: '))
while True:  # Loop infinito para min_range >= max_range
    max_range = int(input('Insira o maior número possível dentre os aleatórios: '))
    min_range = int(input('Insira o menor número possível dentre os aleatórios: '))
    if max_range > min_range:
        break
    else:
        print('Valor inválido. Tente novamente.')

for j in range(0, 2):
    # j varia de acordo com o jogador. j = 0: jogador 1, j = 1: jogador 2
    if j == 0:
        print('\nJOGADOR 1')
        sleep(3)
    elif j == 1:
        print('\nJOGADOR 2')
        sleep(5)

    for c in range(0, rodadas):
        # Código será executado pelo valor da variável 'rodadas'
        print('-=' * 15)
        sleep(1)
        print('Ache o valor de x')
        sleep(1)
        # Gerando os números aleatórios
        n1 = int(randint(min_range, max_range))
        n2 = int(randint(min_range, max_range))
        print(f'x = {n1} * {n2}')
        inicio = time()  # Início da contagem do tempo
        n = int(input('Insira o valor de x: '))
        fim = time()  # Fim da contagem do tempo
        tempo_total = fim - inicio
        print(f'Tempo: {tempo_total:.2f} segundos')

        if j == 0:
            gabarito_j1.append(n1 * n2)
            respostas_j1.append(n)
            tempo_j1.append(tempo_total)
        elif j == 1:
            gabarito_j2.append(n1 * n2)
            respostas_j2.append(n)
            tempo_j2.append(tempo_total)

for cont, n in enumerate(gabarito_j1):
    # Se o valor em 'gabarito' for igual ao de 'respostas' "Correto" será adicionado na lista
    # Senão, "Incorreto" será adicionado em resultado_j2
    if respostas_j1[cont] == n:
        resultado_j1.append('Correto')
    else:
        resultado_j1.append('Incorreto')
num_de_acertos_j1 = resultado_j1.count('Correto')

for cont, n in enumerate(gabarito_j2):
    # Se o valor em 'gabarito' for igual ao de 'respostas' "Correto" será adicionado na lista
    # Senão, "Incorreto" será adicionado em resultado_j2
    if respostas_j2[cont] == n:
        resultado_j2.append('Correto')
    else:
        resultado_j2.append('Incorreto')
num_de_acertos_j2 = resultado_j2.count('Correto')
print('')
print('-=' * 30)
print('DADOS DO JOGADOR 1')
print(f'O jogador 1 acertou {num_de_acertos_j1} num total de {(sum(tempo_j1)):.2f} segundos')
print(f'-=' * 30)
print('DADOS DO JOGADOR 2')
print(f'O jogador 2 acertou {num_de_acertos_j2} num total de {(sum(tempo_j2)):.2f} segundos')
print('-=' * 30)

# Analisando casos onde um jogador obteve mais acertos do que outro
if num_de_acertos_j1 > num_de_acertos_j2:
    print(f''
          f'O jogador 1 venceu por {num_de_acertos_j1 - num_de_acertos_j2}'
          f' pontos de diferença')
elif num_de_acertos_j2 > num_de_acertos_j1:
    print(f'O jogador 2 venceu por {num_de_acertos_j2 - num_de_acertos_j1}'
          f' pontos de diferença')

# Analisando casos onde os jogadores empataram e o desempate é no tempo
elif num_de_acertos_j1 == num_de_acertos_j2:
    if sum(tempo_j1) < sum(tempo_j2):
        print(f'O jogador 1 venceu por {(sum(tempo_j2) - sum(tempo_j1)):.2f}'
              f' segundos de diferença')
    elif sum(tempo_j1) > sum(tempo_j2):
        print(f'O jogador 2 venceu por {(sum(tempo_j1) - sum(tempo_j2)):.2f}'
              f' segundos de diferença')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que deve fazer é:

- Deixar nomes de variáveis claros e legíveis, no seu caso em português para que o seu código se assemelhe o mais possível a pseudocódigo.
- Utilizar funções em todos os pedaços de lógica que faça sentido, pois fica com o código todo dividido em pequenos blocos que tem um nome associado, representando o que aquele bloco faz. Para além disso fica com uma visão geral sobre como funciona ao ler apenas as chamadas de função no seu código principal.
- Repetir código o mínimo possível, pois isto acaba a dificultar a leitura e deixa o leitor mais confuso sobre o que o programa faz.
- Evitar ter números mágicos no código, que só o autor sabe o seu significado.

Estes princípios são todos os que devem ser aplicados em refatorizações de código, para deixar o código enxuto, e tanto são válidos para o seu programa como para outro qualquer.

Aplicando estas ideias no seu código, sem perder demasiado tempo, cheguei a este resultado:

```
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint

# Listas do jogador 1
gabarito_j1 = list()  # Lista com respostas da multiplicação
respostas_j1 = list()  # Lista com os inputs do usuário
tempo_j1 = list()  # Lista com o tempo levado pelo usuário
# Listas do jogador 2
gabarito_j2 = list()
respostas_j2 = list()
tempo_j2 = list()

JOGADOR1 = 0
JOGADOR2 = 1


def respostas_corretas(gabaritos, respostas):
    corretas = 0
    for gabarito, resposta in zip(gabaritos, respostas):
        if gabarito == resposta:
            corretas += 1

    return corretas


def mostra_dados(num_jogador, num_de_acertos, tempo):
    print('-=' * 30)
    print(f'DADOS DO JOGADOR {num_jogador}')
    print(f'O jogador {num_jogador} acertou {num_de_acertos} num total de {(sum(tempo)):.2f} segundos')


def le_resultado(n1, n2):
    print(f'x = {n1} * {n2}')
    inicio = time()  # Início da contagem do tempo
    valor_lido = int(input('Insira o valor de x: '))
    fim = time()  # Fim da contagem do tempo
    tempo = fim - inicio
    print(f'Tempo: {tempo:.2f} segundos')
    return tempo, valor_lido


def mostrar_vencedor(num_de_acertos_j1, num_de_acertos_j2, tempo_j1, tempo_j2):
    # Analisando casos onde um jogador obteve mais acertos do que outro
    if num_de_acertos_j1 > num_de_acertos_j2:
        print(f'O jogador 1 venceu por {num_de_acertos_j1 - num_de_acertos_j2} pontos de diferença')
    elif num_de_acertos_j2 > num_de_acertos_j1:
        print(f'O jogador 2 venceu por {num_de_acertos_j2 - num_de_acertos_j1} pontos de diferença')  
    else: # Analisando casos onde os jogadores empataram e o desempate é no tempo
        if sum(tempo_j1) < sum(tempo_j2):
            print(f'O jogador 1 venceu por {(sum(tempo_j2) - sum(tempo_j1)):.2f} segundos de diferença')
        elif sum(tempo_j1) > sum(tempo_j2):
            print(f'O jogador 2 venceu por {(sum(tempo_j1) - sum(tempo_j2)):.2f} segundos de diferença')


rodadas = int(input('Insira o número de rodadas: '))
while True:  # Loop infinito para min_range >= max_range
    maximo = int(input('Insira o maior número possível dentre os aleatórios: '))
    minimo = int(input('Insira o menor número possível dentre os aleatórios: '))
    if maximo > minimo:
        break
    print('Valor inválido. Tente novamente.')

for jogador in range(0, 2):
    print(f'JOGADOR {jogador + 1}')
    sleep(3)

    for rodada in range(0, rodadas):
        print('-=' * 15)
        sleep(1)
        print('Ache o valor de x')
        sleep(1)
        # Gerando os números aleatórios
        n1 = int(randint(minimo, maximo))
        n2 = int(randint(minimo, maximo))
        tempo, valor_lido = le_resultado(n1, n2)

        if jogador == JOGADOR1:
            gabarito_j1.append(n1 * n2)
            respostas_j1.append(valor_lido)
            tempo_j1.append(tempo)
        elif jogador == JOGADOR2:
            gabarito_j2.append(n1 * n2)
            respostas_j2.append(valor_lido)
            tempo_j2.append(tempo)

num_de_acertos_j1 = respostas_corretas(gabarito_j1, respostas_j1)
num_de_acertos_j2 = respostas_corretas(gabarito_j2, respostas_j2)
print()
mostra_dados(1, num_de_acertos_j1, tempo_j1)
mostra_dados(2, num_de_acertos_j2, tempo_j2)
print()
mostrar_vencedor(num_de_acertos_j1, num_de_acertos_j2, tempo_j1, tempo_j2)
```

Repare que tem agora várias funções e olhando para o código principal é muito mais fácil ter uma ideia do que o programa realmente faz. Para além disso você tinha (e ainda tem) vários blocos de código que se repetiam para os dois jogadores.

Para mim como a lógica é precisamente igual mas para cada jogador, acho que criar uma classe para o jogador englobando a lógica é o ideal, pois evita as variáveis globais que tem e algum do código repetido que ainda existe. Naturalmente será mais difícil para quem não esteja dentro destes conceitos de programação.

Aplicando esse passo ficaria com algo como:

```
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint


class Jogador:
    def __init__(self, numero):
        self.numero = numero
        self.gabaritos = list()  # Lista com respostas da multiplicação
        self.respostas = list()  # Lista com os inputs do usuário
        self.tempos = list()  # Lista com o tempo levado pelo usuário
        self.corretas = 0

    def calcular_respostas_corretas(self):
        self.corretas = 0
        for gabarito, resposta in zip(self.gabaritos, self.respostas):
            if gabarito == resposta:
                self.corretas += 1

    def mostra_dados(self):
        print('-=' * 30)
        print(f'DADOS DO JOGADOR {self.numero}')
        print(f'O jogador {self.numero} acertou {self.corretas} num total de {self.tempo():.2f} segundos')

    def adicionar_resposta(self, conta, valor_lido, tempo_resposta):
        self.gabaritos.append(conta)
        self.respostas.append(valor_lido)
        self.tempos.append(tempo_resposta)

    def tempo(self):
        return sum(self.tempos)


def le_resultado(n1, n2):
    print(f'x = {n1} * {n2}')
    inicio = time()  # Início da contagem do tempo
    valor_lido = int(input('Insira o valor de x: '))
    fim = time()  # Fim da contagem do tempo
    tempo = fim - inicio
    print(f'Tempo: {tempo:.2f} segundos')
    return tempo, valor_lido


def mostrar_vencedor(jogador1, jogador2):
    # Analisando casos onde um jogador obteve mais acertos do que outro
    if jogador1.corretas > jogador2.corretas:
        print(f'O jogador 1 venceu por {jogador1.corretas - jogador2.corretas} pontos de diferença')
    elif num_de_acertos_j2 > num_de_acertos_j1:
        print(f'O jogador 2 venceu por {jogador2.corretas - jogador1.corretas} pontos de diferença')
    else:  # Analisando casos onde os jogadores empataram e o desempate é no tempo
        if sum(tempo_j1) < sum(tempo_j2):
            print(f'O jogador 1 venceu por {(jogador2.tempo() - jogador1.tempo()):.2f} segundos de diferença')
        elif sum(tempo_j1) > sum(tempo_j2):
            print(f'O jogador 2 venceu por {(jogador1.tempo() - jogador2.tempo()):.2f} segundos de diferença')


rodadas = int(input('Insira o número de rodadas: '))
while True:
    maximo = int(input('Insira o maior número possível dentre os aleatórios: '))
    minimo = int(input('Insira o menor número possível dentre os aleatórios: '))
    if maximo > minimo:
        break
    print('Valor inválido. Tente novamente.')

jogadores = [Jogador(1), Jogador(2)]
for jogador in jogadores:
    print(f'JOGADOR {jogador.numero}')
    sleep(3)

    for rodada in range(0, rodadas):
        print('-=' * 15)
        sleep(1)
        print('Ache o valor de x')
        sleep(1)
        # Gerando os números aleatórios
        n1 = int(randint(minimo, maximo))
        n2 = int(randint(minimo, maximo))
        tempo, valor_lido = le_resultado(n1, n2)
        jogador.adicionar_resposta(n1 * n2, valor_lido, tempo)

print()
for jogador in jogadores:
    jogador.calcular_respostas_corretas()
    jogador.mostra_dados()

print()
mostrar_vencedor(jogadores[0], jogadores[1])
```

Neste ultimo cenário já não tem a repetição das listas de respostas e tempos para cada jogador, assim como não os tem como variáveis globais, pois cada jogador é representado por uma classe com toda a informação que este deve conter. Também não tem repetido a parte de colocação dos valores nessas mesmas listas, que agora é feito pelo método `adicionar_resposta` da classe `Jogador`. 
Para além disso os jogadores fazem parte agora de uma lista de jogadores, pelo que alterar o jogo para 3 ou mais jogadores seria muito mais fácil e necessitava apenas de ajustar a parte da vitória, pois o resto já é flexível.

Mas como já disse anteriormente, esta solução poderá ser mais difícil de compreender para quem nunca tenha visto conceitos de programação orientada a objetos.

Answer (score 2):

Conheço duas maneiras: Fluxogramas e pseudocódigo

1.Fluxogramas 
São representações gráficas de algoritmos, isso simplifica o entendimento e deixa seu programa muito mais transparente, mesmo que talvez você não conheça as ferramentas recomendo tentar criar algo, ajuda não só as outras pessoas a entenderem o seu código, mas mostra à você possíveis melhoras a serem feitas no algoritmo.[image: Um exemplo de fluxograma:]
Se tiver interesse tente a ferramenta https://www.draw.io

Pseudocódigo
É uma forma de escrever algoritmos mais próximos da nossa linguagem natural
Exemplo:

[image: Exemplo simples de pseudocódigo]